# Can Python evaluate a while loop after executing the code?

Tags: python-3.x

Other languages allow you to something like

Do

*loop body*

While *conditions*

This guarantees the loop runs at least once, and allows you to have user input determine the conditions inside the loop without having to initialize them first. Does Python support this type of loop?

Edit: 
I'm not looking for a work around. I went with

```
quitstr = self._search_loop()
while quitstr != 'y':
    quitstr = self._search_loop()
```

I am only asking whether or not Python supports post-execution loop evaluation

Comment: Python does not have a do-while loop.

Comment: @RemyJ Somebody failed early in my coding education (probably me). I had always thought "do while" loops and "while" loops were synonymous.

Comment: They​ are similar, what sets them apart it the position of the condition. In the while loop the test is done before entering the loop, that means that your instructions within the loop might never gets executed. Where as in the do-while loop the 
instructions will get executed at least once.

Comment: To correct the failure in your coding education I suggest that you take a look at [do-while](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop.htm),
[while](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_while_loop.htm) and [while-True](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/).  ;-)

Comment: The last link will give you an alternative to the do-while loop and why it is not present in Python (check the references in the bottom of the page for that).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you are trying to do.But You can implement a do-while loop like this:

```
while True:
  loop body
  if break_condition:
    break
```

or

```
loop body
while not break_condition:
    loop body
```

Answer (score 1):

An option for this situation is to set the `while` loop to `True` and do the condition checking at the end:

```
should_break = False

while True:
    # do the loop body

    # AND potentially do something that impacts the 
    # value of should_break

    if X > Y:
        should_break = True

    if should_break == True:
        break                # This breaks out of the while loop
```

As long as should_break remains False, this code will:

1. Run at least once
2. Continue to run

But once the `X > Y` condition becomes `True`, the while loop will end.